# AOSP: How to Build gradle app in AOSP?

Tags: android

I have googled and found below to build gradle app in AOSP with make file. Below is what I have tried,

1. Project_folder-> Android.mk call inside make files (app/Android.mk)
2. Added a new make file, Android.mk of project_folder/app and map the respective src, res and Manifest files

But what I didnt get here is, no where the build.gradle is linked to Android.mk, so how the system will understand to build the file app/build.radle (where we add all app level dependencies). Also, Project_folder/build.gradle is not required to add any changes?

So steps 1 & 2 resulting in errors with build.gradle dependencies.

Some portals suggesting in adding srcSets in app/build.gradle. Even then how do we build the app from make file without linking it to Android.mk?

In root level, I believe we need make the system to understand to build apps with gradle structure than just adding the make files in application?

Please guide me if there is any solution to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to transfer your gradle dependencies in the Android mk file. You may start from scratch or start with an existing one at: [AOSP sample apps](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/refs/heads/master/apps/)

I guess you make start by looking into the following documentation:

1. [Android.mk file syntax specification](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/4e159d95ebf23b5f72bb707b0cb1518ef96b3d03/docs/ANDROID-MK.TXT)
2. [mk-project Documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/mk-project/latest/mk-project.pdf)
3. [GNU make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

Comment: I have some proto files. How to build these files?

Comment: The [TV](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/TV/+/refs/tags/android-8.1.0_r77) package in android uses proto files. You should look into the Android.mk files of this package.

Comment: @XueQing have you checked how protos are handled in AOSP?